# Smarty alternate view elements in foreach loop

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I am trying to figure out a way to cycle through the inner loop view items in the following manner:

First:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3 class="padding-bot-20">{$row->service}</h3>{$row->content}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{$this->images->frontend_check_image($row->main_image)}" alt="Service">
</div>
```

Second:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{$this->images->frontend_check_image($row->main_image)}" alt="Service">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3 class="padding-bot-20">{$row->service}</h3>{$row->content}
</div>
```

and so on... so the presentation is content/image, image/content, content/image .etc.

This is the main code:

```
    <div class="container">
        {if count($row_services) == 0}
            No services published.
        {else}
            {assign var=i value=0}
            {foreach from=$row_services item=row}
                <div class="row scroll-animated-from-bottom {if $i > 0}padding-top-50{/if}" id="service-data-1">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h3 class="padding-bot-20">{$row->service}</h3>{$row->content}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{$this->images->frontend_check_image($row->main_image)}" alt="Service">
                    </div>
                </div>
            {capture assign=i}{$i+1}{/capture}
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
    </div>
```

I know how to accomplish this is php, but I'm unsure how to do it in smarty. I'm trying to avoid having any child views.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could come up with. If anyone has a more elegant solution, feel free to share:

```
    <div class="container">
        {if count($row_services) == 0}
            No services published.
        {else}
            {assign var=i value=0}
            {foreach from=$row_services item=row}
                <div class="row scroll-animated-from-bottom {if $i > 0}padding-top-50{/if}" id="service-data-1">
                    {if ($i % 2 == 0)}
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h3 class="padding-bot-20">{$row->service}</h3>{$row->content}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{$this->images->frontend_check_image($row->main_image)}" alt="Service">
                        </div>
                    {else}
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{$this->images->frontend_check_image($row->main_image)}" alt="Service">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h3 class="padding-bot-20">{$row->service}</h3>{$row->content}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                </div>
            {capture assign=i}{$i+1}{/capture}
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
</div>
```